# Python Resample: How do I keep NaN as NaN?

Tags: python, pandas-resample

When resample from monthly data to quarterly, I want my last value NaN to remain as NaN. How should I tweak my code?

Thank you

```
     HS6P1
```

Jan1989  69.9
Feb1989  59.3
Mar1989  83.5
Apr1989  100.4
May1989  101.4
Jun1989  100.3
Jul1989  98
Aug1989  91.7
Sep1989  82.4
Oct1989  91.3
Nov1989  72.6
Dec1989  NaN

[image]

```
df=pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols='A:D', na_values='ND', index_col=0, header=0)
df.index.names = ['Period']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)


q0= pd.Series(df['HS6P1'], index=df.index)

m1 = q0.resample('Q').sum()
```

**Current Output**
Period
1989-03-31    212.7
1989-06-30    302.1
1989-09-30    272.1
1989-12-31    163.9

**Desired Output**
Period
1989-03-31    212.7
1989-06-30    302.1
1989-09-30    272.1
1989-12-31    NaN

Comment: why not post the actual dataframe data, not a screenshot.

Comment: @inquirer: Posted the actual data. Pls assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this. But if you have NaNs elsewhere, then the sums in that part will be NaNs. [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29382?ysclid=lbev9koj8j736272380) is information on this topic. `np.nan + 1`, then the output will be `nan`. nan turns everything it touches into nan.

```
res = q0.resample('Q').apply(lambda x: np.sum(x.values))
```

And another option.
I don't know if it will fit? Used the min_count=3 parameter. Theoretically, there are three values in a quarter, if some values are missing, then there will be NaN.

```
m1 = q0.resample('Q').sum(min_count=3)
```

If you need to return NaN exactly in the last quarter, if there is at least one empty value there.

```
def my_func(x):
    return [x.sum(), np.isnan(x).any()]

qqq = q0.resample('Q').apply(my_func)

if qqq[-1][1] == True:
    qqq[-1][0] = np.nan

qqq = pd.Series(qqq.str[0], index=qqq.index)
```